# What's the conversion of ms^-2 to Watts?

Tags: gravity, electricity

I'm looking to find out **how many Watts gravity would be** if it were in Watts rather than ms^-2.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense because your units don't match up.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating further?

Comment: What are the base units of Watts? (i.e., in terms of meters, kilograms and seconds, how are they combined to make a watt?)

Comment: Watt as in electricity. I feel like I may have used the wrong terminology.

Comment: And Watts in electricity (and everywhere else) is a unit of power, that is, energy per unit time. And the force from gravity is not measured as power.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct conversion as Watts and the gravitational field strength g have different units.

g, as you said, is in $ms^{-2}$; it has the units of an acceleration, $Length(L)^{1}$ and $Time(T)^{-2}$.

Watts, however, are a measure of Energy supplied per unit time. So let's break it down!

Joules, as we can derive from Work, have dimensions of Newtown-metres. A Newton is derived from a Mass(M) times acceleration, and so Joules must have Dimensions $MLT^{-2}\times L = ML^{2}T^{-2}$, and thus Watts have dimensions $ML^{2}T^{-3}$.

Because they have totally different dimensions, it wouldn't make sense to convert between g and Watts directly. By directly, I mean using a scalar factor (which is dimensionless), which is how I interpreted the question.

What you could imagine is the work-done per second moving some kind of test-mass (1kg) at a speed 1$ms^{-1}$ through a uniform gravitational field of strength g, but I don't think this tells us much...